# How to write different layout in CSV in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have detailed record in dataframe and that needs to write in .csv file with custom header and trailer record like ' Record type(00)+date+time' for header and record type(100)+count of detailed record in trailer. How to add 3 different layout in csv file?

My file layout

00/20190413/230000

12/asa/adf/erdaf/dafad/3434/34k

13/xxx/yyy/gggf/dafad/3430/35

99/00000002

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html lists your csv options.

Comment: Can you pls suggest how to achieve my output file layout ? Is it possible for any other file format ?

Comment: We are using things in parallel as well. No notion of what those fields mean on header and trailer, the last fields.